# Php parse always has href

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

Im trying to call my prices in this api which isnt a problem but the problem is the prices have links on them instead of regular text, can anyone see what im doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$x = file_get_contents("http://sandbox.api.shopping.com/publisher/3.0/rest/GeneralSearch?apiKey=authorized-key&trackingId=7000610&categoryId=7185&numItems=8&printers");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
foreach($xml->categories->category->items->product as $item)
{
print '<div style="float: left; width: 120px; padding: 10px; overflow: auto; display: block;">';
print '<a rel="nofollow" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\', \'/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591\']);" href="'.$item->productOffersURL.'"><img src="'.$item->images->image[0]->sourceURL.'" width="100"></a>';
print '<img src="'.$item->rating->ratingImage[0]->sourceURL.'" width="91">';
print "<br/>".l($item->name, $item->productOffersURL, array(), NULL, NULL, TRUE);
//print "<br/>".l($item->shortDescription, $item->productOffersURL, array(), NULL, NULL, TRUE);
// this is where the prices are.
print "<br/>" .l($item->minPrice, $item->productOffersURL, array(), NULL, NULL, TRUE);
print "<br/>".l($item->maxPrice, $item->productOffersURL, array(), NULL, NULL, TRUE);
print '</div>';
}
?>
```

this is the dom firebug is returning.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 120px; padding: 10px; overflow: auto; display: block;">

<a href="http://www.shopping.com/Canon-Canon-EOS-400D-Twin-Lens-Kit-Silver-Body-18-55mm-EF-75-300mm-f-4-5-6-Lens/prices~linkin_id-7000610" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/outgoing/article_exit_link/789591']);" rel="nofollow"><img width="100" src="http://di1.shopping.com/images/pi/cf/86/d8/58898587-100x100-0-0.jpg?p=p2.48bc03c211719c7871ea&amp;a=2&amp;c=1&amp;l=7000610&amp;t=110620123546&amp;r=1"></a>

<img width="91" src="http://img.shopping.com/sc/pr/sdc_stars_sm_4.5.gif"><br>

<a href="http://www.shopping.com/Canon-Canon-EOS-400D-Twin-Lens-Kit-Silver-Body-18-55mm-EF-75-300mm-f-4-5-6-Lens/prices~linkin_id-7000610">Canon EOS 400D / EOS Rebel XTi Digital Camera with 18-55mm and 75-300mm lenses</a><br>

<a href="http://www.shopping.com/Canon-Canon-EOS-400D-Twin-Lens-Kit-Silver-Body-18-55mm-EF-75-300mm-f-4-5-6-Lens/prices~linkin_id-7000610">598.00</a><br>

<a href="http://www.shopping.com/Canon-Canon-EOS-400D-Twin-Lens-Kit-Silver-Body-18-55mm-EF-75-300mm-f-4-5-6-Lens/prices~linkin_id-7000610">990.00</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Inspect it with firebug, see if they are being included in the `<a>`

Comment: Please show the HTML-Dom (Chrome -> right click -> inspect element)

Comment: yeah they are, with the full link thats on the image inside of it.

Comment: It would be easier for us, if you post a part of the DOM. Try to write a correct <img /> tag. Yours is not closed.

Comment: you can see the xml file here, it doesnt give any indication of the prices being linked 

http://sandbox.api.shopping.com/publisher/3.0/rest/GeneralSearch?apiKey=authorized-key&trackingId=7000610&categoryId=7185&numItems=8&printers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Image-tag is not closed. This could be the problem. Please use a correct notation

```
<img /> <!--instead of <img> -->
```

**EDIT:**

What does function l() do?

```
print "<br/>".l($item->maxPrice, $item->productOffersURL, array(), NULL, NULL, TRUE);
```

Try to use

```
print "<br/>".$item->maxPrice;
```

instead

Comment: that was one of the 1st things I tried but it still gives the same results.

Comment: well that worked, i tried it before but i was getting errors i guess i was forgetting a syntax or something, thanks